# How to "touch" a file using Swift on OSX

Tags: swift, macos, file, cocoa, command

I would like to touch a folder using Swift using a native command similar to the command line:

touch myfile.txt

What is the best way of doing this?

I can create folders OK. My question is how to touch the folder (ie update its modification date) without affecting the folders contents.

I was exploring whether there was an API to do this. I expect you can invoke a CLI command to do this. My research has not turned up a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for invoking a CLI command, you can do this with `NSFileManager`.

First, let's have a look at the *attributes* of a file (or folder):

```
let manager = NSFileManager()

do {
    let attr = try manager.attributesOfItemAtPath(yourFilePath)
    print(attr)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

What you get with `.attributesOfItemAtPath` is an NSDictionary containing all the file/folder attributes, including the modification date.

You can *set* these attributes with `.setAttributes`, here's your example for setting the modification date to the current date:

```
let newAttributes = [NSFileModificationDate: NSDate()]

do {
    try manager.setAttributes(newAttributes, ofItemAtPath: yourFilePath)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternately you can use the `URL` class:

```
var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
resourceValues.contentModificationDate = Date()
try? url.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
```

Note `url` must be a `var` since it is supposedly modified by this.